# Looping through dictionary to insert value to an object

Tags: python

Consider I have the following dictionary:

```
dic={}
dic["var1"]=val1
dic["var2"]=val2
```

Now I have another object which contains two properties: `var1` and `var2` .
I would like to run a loop within the object's method such as (pseudo code):

```
for key, value in dic
  self.key=value
```

so that `self.var1=val2` and `self.var2=val2`

How can I implement it in python?

Meir

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> class Obj(object):
...     pass
... 
>>> obj = Obj()
>>> for key, value in {'var1':5, 'var2':6}.iteritems():
...     setattr(obj, key, value)
... 
>>> obj.var1
5
>>> obj.var2
6
```

Here I am obligated to say something like "why not just use a dict?"

Answer (score 2):

You can use "setattr":

```python
class Test:
  var1 = "Cheese"
  var2 = "Toast"


dic = {}
dic["var1"] = "NewCheese"
dic["var2"] = "NewToast"

oTest = Test()

for key in dic.keys():
  setattr(oTest, key, dic[key])

print "Var1 = ", oTest.var1
print "Var2 = ", oTest.var2

# 
# Result
#
# Var1 =  NewCheese
# Var2 =  NewToast
#
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#setattr .

Answer (score 2):

You can update the internal [__dict__](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__dict__#object.__dict__) attribute which is a dictionnary that contains all the members of the object.

```
class MyObj:
    def __init__(self, member_dict):
        self.__dict__.update(member_dict)

dic={}
dic["var1"]=val1
dic["var2"]=val2

obj = MyObj(dic)

print obj.var1
>>> val1
print obj.var2
>>> val2
```